# How to compare 2 variable using php like this?

Tags: php, variables

How to compare 2 variable using php like this ?

```
$aaa = "1234567890qwertyuiopsdflkjwerouioiuweewjkee";
$bbb = "1234567890qwertyuiop";
```

How to check

```
if(first char to twenty char of $aaa == $bbb)
{ echo "same"; }
else
{ echo "not same"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are searching for [strncmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php):

> This function is similar to strcmp(), with the difference that you can specify the (upper limit of the) number of characters from each string to be used in the comparison.

```
if(strncmp($aaa, $bbb, 20) == 0) {
    # First twenty characters match.
} else {
    # First twenty characters don't match.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$aaafirst20 = $small = substr($aaa, 0, 20);

if(strcmp($aaafirst20 , $bbb){

}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You can use `strcmp` function for the same.

[PHP docs @ strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

```
if(strcmp($aaa,$bbb)){

     echo "same";

   } else {

      echo "not same";

   }
```

Comment: Wrong, they are not looking for `same`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos()` to check if `$bbb` is found in `$aaa`, and starts at position 0.

```
if (strpos($aaa, $bbb) === 0) {
    echo 'Same';
}
else echo 'Not same';
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/As5OQ)

Answer (score 0):

Your exact solution would be

```
// first reduce a to its first 20 characters
$trimmed = substr($aaa, 0, 20);

// now compare with b
if($trimmed == $bbb){
    // same
}
```

Or, all in one line

```
if(substr($aaa, 0, 20) == $bbb){
    // same
}
```